# mysql calculation differences between two number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a blog. I wrote simple voting system. I might be wrong about the idea. i have a table like this

id title article TotalVotes VoteSum

when someone upvote article TotelVotes gets one point if someone downvote the article the VoteSum cloumn gets 1 point

when I display the article's vote i do this

```
<?php
$Vote = $ROW['TotelVotes']-$ROW['VoteSum'];
?>
```

it works just fine but on my front page I want to show top articles so I made this mysql query

```
SELECT TotalVotes-VoteSum AS diff FROM `articles` ORDER BY `diff`  DESC
```

when i do this I recieve numbers like this 18446744073709551615 this happens for example when TotalVotes less than VoteSum

DATA TYPE IS INT UNSIGNED

what do I do wrong? Could you please help me? thanks.

Comment: Try ...[ABS(TotalVotes-VoteSum)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)...Or it could be an issue because of the data type(s) of the columns.

Comment: what are the data types of TotalVotes and VoteSum ?

Comment: and second question, you want to be able to retrieve negative values, don't you ?

Comment: data types are INT UNSIGNED

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `IF`

```
SELECT IF(TotalVotes >= VoteSum, TotalVotes-VoteSum, VoteSum-TotalVotes) AS diff 
FROM `articles` 
ORDER BY `diff`  DESC
```

**UPDATE**

if you want to get negative values, make those columns as `INT SIGNED` so you can get negatives. And directly run your own query,

```
SELECT TotalVotes-VoteSum AS diff 
FROM `articles` 
ORDER BY `diff`  DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*SIGNED INTEGER*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb519/3)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT cast(TotalVotes as int)-cast(VoteSum as int) AS diff
FROM `articles`
ORDER BY `diff`  DESC
```

This will fix the problem if the signing issue is in the database.  By default, the `int` data type is signed (in MySQL and in every other database that I know of).

Comment: Best answer yet! Beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

Use math function `ABS`

```
SELECT ABS(TotalVotes-VoteSum) AS diff 
FROM `articles` 
ORDER BY `diff`  DESC
```

Comment: @Cthulhu, the OP tagged as mysql and `ABS()` is legal function. [Check it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecb5f/5)

Comment: But the OP's problem was with `unsigned` datatypes. And if I set `unsigned` in you fiddle i get an error: [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/927c4/1).

Comment: @Cthulhu, do you see the date of OP update and date when I answer to the question.

Comment: Even in the first revision of the question problem clearly was in the overflowing, and using `ABS` could not hypothetically help due to the fact that, as mentioned before, diffenence will be calculated (or attempted to be so) before being passed to `ABS`.